# Facebook login on Meteor mobile App (cordova)?

Tags: facebook, cordova, authentication, meteor

I'm looking to build a mobile application using Meteor+Cordova. Looking to get the Facebook login to work first. Apparently the default accounts-facebook package doesn't work so I looked around atmosphere and only found "particle4dev:cordova-fb", so I tried using that.

I'm a bit confused about the app developer stuff. Normally I just use it for my website so its quite straight forward. In terms of setting up the login details (such as ID and token), do I register as if it's an IOS app? Or do I still register as if its web?? It asks me to download XCode SDK for FB, is that what I'm supposed to be doing? is the package mentioned above what I should be using, or are there more mainstream options available?

Comment: I don't get it. Who said accounts-facebook doesn't work? This is not true, accounts-facebook is tested with Meteor/Cordova integration and works for both iOS and Android

Comment: Maybe I have been looking at older posts? So if it works, do I register an ios key on the Facebook Developer platform, and then insert it into some sort of settings file in my meteor app?

Comment: Actually I added the accounts-facebook package and it did not work on mobile. I don't even see the login button, are you sure accounts-facebook works with cordova?

Comment: it is supposed to work. if it doesn't report it as issue with a repro

Comment: Maybe I'm doing it all wrong then. Can you sort of, point me in the right direction? All I did was add the package and accounts-ui, and throw in a {{> loginButtons}}. The button displays on web but not when I transfer the app to my phone and use it from there

Comment: It is possible that your app simply doesn't connect to server (because they need to be on the same network, etc)

Answer (score 4):

I was also facing problem with accounts-facebook package. It was using in-app cordova browser and failing at the time of oauth handshake.

I added cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.11.0 to app and enabled it for single sign on from developer account on facebook.

If you face any problem then please look at my blog [here](http://www.rishabhsinghal.in/meteor-cordova-facebook-single-sign-on/). I have written a simple tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

If there are still some people to fix this thing, this may help them.

I've just used the latest version on github.

removing the plugin and adding it again like this:

```
meteor add cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-facebook-plugin/tarball/d8b0f6935a7c6e586188bf85f9da88a1c160790b
```

This above code with particle4dev:cordova-fb worked like a charm on android and it should work on ios devices also. It seems they fixed the issue in their updates.

Comment: Had cordova:com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect@0.11.0, and it worked on android, but not iOS. Replaced it with this one here, and now it's finally working on ios and android!

Answer (score 1):

accounts-facebook package works fine. I just created a new project and tried, you can refer to this screencast http://recordit.co/7JNpDSzJ9m

if you are using accounts-facebook, you need to register the app as web on fb

Comment: I see. I'll try it some more. But is there a way to have it login using the facebook app on the phone (like how a real native app does facebook login), or does it always open a popup browser like in your cast?

Comment: if you are using accounts-facebook, right now it always opens in cordova's InAppBrowser as popup. To use the native facebook account on phone -> particle4dev:cordova-fb should do that, I couldn't get it to work as it was showing an error with settings.json sample in readme. Will try again and post if I can get it working.

Comment: I have been trying particle4dev:cordova-fb. I couldn't get it to work though, I set my settings.JSON properly, but the dependency (cordova's facebook login plugin) has a bug where if you add the plugin using the "cordova plugin registry", it messes up your Facebook SDK.

What you're supposed to do is to re-add the FacebookSDK framework into Xcode, but its all confusing ot me because the project does not exist in xcode until after it successfully builds, so how do I add the FacebookSDK right now?

Comment: this worked for me. still it does feel a bit weird to have all working without adding any code. now i have to realise how to use my own buttons and listen the events myself.

Comment: actually it does work on the simulator and on the browser, but when testing on the device loginButtons actually doesn't show up.

weirdly enough i think in a previous test ( where i had more stuff going on ) it actually worked, although i can't reproduce

Answer (score 0):

So I've been trying to use  particle4dev:cordova-fb for awhile now. For those who are confused about how to implement it. First you add it as a package to your existing app. Then you add the facebookconnect cordova plugin. Then you add the android platform. Then try and run the android platform (meteor run android --settings settings.json). This should fail. Now go through the steps on implementing facebookconnect on Android. This should make sure it works on android now. However even after doing all of this and getting it to work, it still simply opens up the in app browser on android for some reason.

Comment: On the IOS side, there is a known bug that the facebook cordova plugin gives you a messed up version of FacebookSDK if you install the plugin through the registry. You're supposed to replace teh FacebookSDK in XCode manually (Not sure how this is done, not familiar with XCode). Anyone familiar with this?