# facebook login using meteor cordova app

Tags: cordova, meteor, facebook-login

I'm implementing facebook login with cordova app, but I'm not able to understand which configuration needed to do in facebook app for this facebook login using meteor cordova. I've done the following steps:

1. create app
2. add website as platform
3. add Valid OAuth redirect URIs(https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html,http://localhost:3000/oauthcallback.html,http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close)
4. add website url ("http://localhost:3000")
5. added phonegap facebook connect plugin
6. below code in my mobile-config.js

   App.configurePlugin('com.phonegap.plugins.facebookconnect', {
       APP_ID: '',
       APP_NAME: ''
   });
7. I added following code in settings.json file

   "facebook": {
       "appId": "",
       "secret": ""
     }
8. I added this code at server side js

   ServiceConfiguration.configurations.insert({
       service: 'facebook',
       appId: '',
       secret:""
     });

I'm able to login in web but not able to login in cordova app. i'm getting following error

> given url is not allowed by the application configuration : one or
>   more of the given URLs is not allowed by the app’s settings. To use
>   ths URL you must add a valid native platform in your app’s settings

can anyone help me to config my facebook app?

Comment: Did you find this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26356661/facebook-login-on-meteor-mobile-app-cordova

Comment: yes i used same cordova phongap plugin. i am able to open facebook login page but there is one error given url is not allowed by the application configuration : one or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the app’s settings. To use ths URL you must add a valid native platform in your app’s settings

Comment: yes obviously then and than i can run my app in my device

Comment: Okay, just checking :) Did you read this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14474122/given-url-is-not-permitted-by-the-application-configuration

Comment: how can its help can you tell me?

Comment: I think your facebook settings on facebook might not 100% accurate. There is an answer: _italic_You need to fill the value for Website with Facebook Login with the value http://localhost/OfferDrive/ to allow Facebook to authenticate that the requests from JavaScript SDK are coming from right place._OfferDrive is this guy's app. And than go to APP base app domain and put in the url. Also, _Settings -> Advanced, add url to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"._

Comment: i added all configuration in my facebook app. i also specified configuration in my question

Comment: Did you go to the advanced tab: Settings -> Advanced, add url to "Valid OAuth redirect URIs"?

Comment: yes i added https://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html,http://localhost:3000/oauthcallback.html,http://localhost:3000/_oauth/facebook?close)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I had a previous problem with `<allow-navigation />` tags in my `config.XML` file which had me looking for the answer in the wrong place. But a closer read says it all,

`...To use ths URL you must add a valid native platform in your app’s settings`

The solution for me was to add an `iOS Platform` to your Facebook App from the Settings page. Make sure you add the correct app bundleID and flip the oauth switch to `Yes`

BTW, I used the`cordova-plugin-facebook4` plugin from this repository `https://github.com/jeduan/cordova-plugin-facebook4`, and I believe it uses the native SDK whiche completely skips the `redirect_uri`. However, I am also using plain `accounts-facebook` for `loginWithFacebook()` from web browsers, and that does require the `redirect_uri` setting.

Answer (score -1):

I had exactly the same problem.

Solution:

you can't use your local development environment (localhost) to do a Facebook login with a meteor/cordova build. This is just working on your desktop machine. You have to deploy your app to your own server or to the meteor test servers via

`meteor deploy myrandomname.meteor.com`

also add via [www.developers.facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com)

(basic page)

app domain:

```
myrandomname.meteor.com
```

(advanced page)
valid OAuth redirect URIs:

```
http://myrandomname.meteor.com:3000/_oauth/facebook?close
```

also don't forget that you are the only one who can login when the app is in test mode. if you would like to allow other people to login while in test mode you have to invite them also via developers.facebook.com to your app.

Comment: thanks i have uploaded on meteor server then i developed app using that url and also add that valid oauthurl but still not getting. But i will try again and let you know

Comment: do you run your app via ```meteor run ios-device --mobile-server=http://myrandomname.meteor.com:3000``` after deploying?

Comment: i will try it again and let you know its my luck if its working