# MeteorJs : deploy to meteor.com with Facebook authentification

Tags: meteor, oauth, facebook-apps

I'm deploying my Meteor App on "http://test_aaaaaaa_bbbbbbb.meteor.com" with this line :

```
meteor deploy test_aaaaaaa_bbbbbbb.meteor.com
```

So in Facebook App dashboardd I've tried to fill the Website URL but Facebooks says that the domain is invalid :

[image]

Is Facebook blocking meteor.com ?

I saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32725659/3636091) someone doing the same thing, but no word on facebook refusing domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well hope this will maybe helps people :

**Facebook doesn't accept url domain with underscores `_`**

simply deploy without underscore in your appName ;)

Comment: is there any doc / link that you found this information from? or did you find this out just from trial and error?